# How can I change the durability of items using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Minecraft 1.8.1 vanilla server and would like to reward certain users. I would like to `/give` some users a 99999/99999 durability renamed Diamond Pickaxe (with all enchantments on it).

How do I use commands to change/repair the durability of items? If possible, using only one command and use `/give`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I give myself a damaged item on 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338339/how-can-i-give-myself-a-damaged-item-on-1-13)

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because the answers here are outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the /give command to create an item with a certain amount of durability by entering a damage value after the quantity. For example, to give a diamond pickaxe that has been used 50 times (1511 durability remaining), use this command:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 50
```

The /give command also allows you to give items with NBT data, including the `Unbreaking` tag. To give a diamond pickaxe that will never break, use this command:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is to do `/give @p <item> 1 <lost durability>` you may have to play around with this but in your way you can do:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 11560
```

This command will say that the durability is -9999 however, this means that the pick will go up to 0 to break. which leaves 9999 uses!

Answer (score -1):

An example of a command to give the player a diamond pickaxe with Unbreaking X:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreaking",lvl:10s}]} 1
```

Tested on Java Edition 1.19.4.

---

On that version, the commands in [OnlyTheBest's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311393/33790) and [SirBenet's answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/193580/33790) failed with the errors:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}

Incorrect argument for command
...pickaxe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}<--[HERE]
```

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 11560

Incorrect argument for command
...pickaxe 1 11560<--[HERE]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add how this command and its effect differ from those in the existing answers.