# Is it possible to give items with a custom max durability?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make custom weapons, tools and armour with a datapack. I want to start with basic extra items like steel armour, ..., and I want to give it slightly higher durability than iron. Is this possible with fairly simple commands?

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but I didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change durability of items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193526/change-durability-of-items)

Comment: I also want to ask, are you okay with a fixed value or not? Will you be able to type the value directly in the command, or will it be variable, using a scoreboard or NBT value?

Comment: I'm fine with a set value, and yes that one answers my question.